# Can I submit an app update that does not comply with iOS 7 or iPhone 5?

Tags: ios

I understand that this isn't specifically a programming related question and I do apologize, but I could use some help.

I have a critical update to submit to the App Store for an existing application. The thing is I don't have time to start resizing everything to fit iPhone 5's longer screen and I do not wish to update my Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode 5 right now. Am I allowed to submit my update like this?

It's a functionality update with some bug fixes but no graphical additions or modifications. It was programmed during the iPhone 4 era and does not fit the iPhone 5 screen perfectly (there's a black section left at the bottom of the screen). It does however work fine on the 5, and I don't foresee any problems functionally. I just want to be sure the review process will not come back and bite me later.

Anyone with experience on the matter?

Comment: The worst apple can do is say, "no"

Comment: Understood, but I'd like to know beforehand, possibly from someone who has successfully or unsuccessfully done what I am trying to do so that I'm not stuck with 2 weeks of wasted time.

Comment: It's up to the reviewer. Since iOS 7 is pretty new they tend to allow critical updates not supporting iOS 7 but iPhone 5 support can be critial. Normally non-iPhone5 updates get refused but if it's working as you say, I would give it a try

Comment: I do NOT have experience with this, but I have released a NEW app last week which wasn't build with iOS7 SDK nor designed for iPhone 5's.

Comment: @Rob That would qualify as experience in my eyes, and is a good answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Why not submit the app and start working on the new version that supports iOS7? What do you have to lose?

Comment: @PaulG Maybe, but keep in mind that apple's reviewing process is based on pure luck :) I have re-published rejected apps without changing ANYthing which resulted in approvements...

Comment: @Rob I hear you there, I've had the same experience, it all depends on the reviewer and what they had for lunch.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently updated my app in the **AppStore** it was compiled with **Xcode 4.6** & target **iOS6** or later. I had **iOS7** installed on my devices and I tested the app and it worked just alright, and after updating the app in the AppStore, it got accepted after two days. So I think just now there is no panic in updating to **iOS7**, there might be some features of your app might not be working on iOS7 devices but its always good to test.

I did not update the new requirements for the icons for iOS7 either, after submission I got only warning email that there are some icons missing for iOS7, but that email was not causing any pain.

Answer (score 0):

In theory your app has to be compiled with the last iOS version to be accepted, you can set the deployment target to other previous versions if you want, but you need to compile with the latest SDK.

As other people has pointed, it's possible that Apple right now is loose with that specification because the version is pretty new, so just try.

Comment: Does the app really have to be compiled with the last iOS version to be accepted? Is there anything in the docs or guidelines about this?

Comment: Apple has been loose with this for some time. They've not yet, to date, forced you to compile with the latest XCode. As long as it doesn't crash on supported iOS versions, you'll be good (for now).